# Trying to execute line after delay in Android Studio with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-handler

Hello I have textView element which i am trying to change its text with delaying.
For example "Hello" -> waits 1 second -> "World" -> waits 1 second -> "How are you?"

When i use my code in terminal in a separate kotlin file it works exactly how i want it.
When i use the code in MainActivity.kt it does wait 1 second and puts the text value only once.
I think it executes all lines simultaneously.But why there is a difference between terminal and ui.

My code has one class file and code in Main Activity

```
class Ball (val Ball: TextView, val time: Long){

    fun textChange(){
        Handler().postDelayed({
            Ball.text = (1..90).random().toString()
        }, time)
    }
}
```

And in MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var resultsList = mutableListOf<Int>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    fun playButtonPressed(view:View){
        Ball(Ball01,1000).textChange()
        Ball(Ball01,1000).textChange()
        Ball(Ball01,1000).textChange()
        Ball(Ball01,1000).textChange()
        Ball(Ball01,1000).textChange()

    }
}
```

Comment: If will exectute five times, with a 1000ms delay, but only the last one to complete will actually change the text to it's duration. You have a wrong idea about doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this way, you're asking to display 5 strings but with the same delay.

To my mind, you have to use a [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer) to display another piece of text following a regular interval.

Here is a sample code

```
class Ball (val Ball: TextView, val messagesList: List<String>){

    private var index = 0
    fun textChange(interval: Long) {
        val time = interval * messagesList.size
        val timer = object: CountDownTimer(time, interval) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                Ball.append(" " +messagesList[index++])
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                //nothing to do
            }
        }
        timer.start()
    }
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var messageList = mutableListOf<String>("Hello", "World", "How are you ?")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    fun playButtonPressed(view:View){
        // will update the text every second during until the list is empty
        Ball(textView, messageList).textChange(1000)
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that all five strings will "display" but 4 of them will be visible for an invisible amount of time. only last one will really win and remain visible.

Comment: see my edited answer, I have added a sample code

Comment: Does not attempt to address this part of the question - `"Hello" -> waits 1 second -> "World" -> waits 1 second -> "How are you?"`

Comment: Does not attempt to address this part of the question - "Hello" -> waits 1 second -> "World" -> waits 1 second -> "How are you?" ı gave this as a simple example my real problem is way more complicated

Comment: @SerdarÇivi, see another example

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to post runnables to the `View` itself, since it has its own access to the handler.

```
fun playButtonPressed(view:View){
    repeat(5) { repeat ->
        val number = (1..90).random().toString()
        val delay = (repeat + 1) * 1000L // repeat starts at 0
        Ball01.postDelayed({ Ball01.text = number }, delay)
    }
}
```

Also you're creating a whole new throwaway `Ball` object just to call that `textChange` function, there's no need to do that. Stick it in a `companion object` if you want that behaviour kept in the `Ball` class, then you can just call `Ball.textChange(textView, delay)` from that `repeat` function